# How to best connect an LCD monitor with DVI-D, Displayport and VGA to a laptop with USB-C?

Tags: display, hdmi, dvi, displayport

What would be the best way to connect [Dell UltraSharp™ U2412M](https://www.dell.com/is/business/p/dell-u2412m/pd) LCD monitor ([specs also here](https://www.displayspecifications.com/en/model/8d00557)) with DVI-D, Displayport and VGA connectors, to my Huawei Matebook X Pro laptop (USB-C)?

By "best way" I mean with good refresh rate (once I connected a monitor and the refresh looked "slow" e.g. when I moved the cursor), simple and cheap.

**Which of these monitor ports should I use? DVI-D, Displayport or VGA?**

I have a USB-C port replicator with HDMI connector, and I don't think there are any (or many) port replicators that would provide these ports anyway. So, I will probably need another conversion from HDMI to one of those three ports? Which one would provide the best results?

Comment: Does your USB-C port replicator support DisplayPort over USB-C? If it doesn’t, you’ll want a different one that does. Please provide the exact make and model.

Answer (score 0):

HDMI and DVI-D are compatible digital signals, so I would recommend a simple HDMI to DVI-D cable.

VGA is an analog signal and would require an active converter and will require you to plug in a power adapter somewhere at your work area, which can be a problem if you don't have an outlet near by.

You will also need an active converter to go from HDMI output to DisplayPort input, so I would avoid that as well.

An HDMI to DVI-D cable is the way to go.